# python-pptxでスライドのサイズを変えたい

Tags: python

python-pptxを使っているのですが,スライドのサイズをA4にしたいです。
どのようにしたら良いでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

[ドキュメント](https://python-pptx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/presentation.html#presentation-objects)に書いてあるように `Presentation` オブジェクトには `slide_height` と `slide_width` が存在しているので、これを書き換えればサイズが変わります。

参考

- [A4 の大きさ](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E7%B4%99%E3%81%AE%E5%AF%B8%E6%B3%95#A.E5.88.97)
- 単位が [English Metric Unit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML_file_formats#DrawingML) (EMU; 1 cm = 360 000 emu) なので注意してください。
- [mm <--> emu の変換器](http://lcorneliussen.de/raw/dashboards/ooxml/)